# trying to select this part in this tutorial

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2qjqqfkH6E
on 5:50
When I try to press  'Control L' when I select a verticle it selects the whole donut for me instead of the icing part. I didn't want to delete the separate icing part too. I just want to delete this  duplicated icing on the donut object.

Edit: had to do it manually but it worked. still is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: If the whole thing is being selected, it's possible the vertex you selected is from the original mesh and not the duplicated part. If this is the case, it means they are close enough to "overlap" (close enough to give you trouble selecting the right one). If you just want the duped part gone, given it is so overlapped, you should be able to select the whole mesh with A, and then press M (merge) and select "By Distance". You will see in the bottom right corner if any vertices were deleted. If it says none are deleted, then it's possible you never duped it in the first place.

Comment: If you run into another situation where you have a piece that is detached (in edit mode), you can select the whole thing by selecting any part of it (edge, face, or vertex) and pressing L (Select linked). Ctrl + L (Select linked all) should work as well, but I personally have always gotten by just fine with simply L.

Comment: Try the other way round. Make sure everything is _deselected_ (Alt-A), and then select any element of the donut, followed by Ctrl-L. Ctrl-I will invert your selection to the icing.